Проблема с настройкой Navigation(Obsolete) в Unity
Я работаю над проектом в Unity 2023.2.14.f1 и столкнулся с проблемой при настройке AI > Navigation. Мне нужно использовать устаревшую версию Navigation (Obsolete), но в моей версии Unity в разделе AI доступен только новый Navigation.
Я пробовал искать настройки в меню и документации, но не смог найти способ вернуть устаревшую версию Navigation. Возможно, я что-то упускаю или существует альтернативный способ решения моей задачи.
